# How do I write a named_scope for one resource through another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, named-scope

I have a groups resource that `belongs_to` Workouts. Workouts can be public or private and are designated as such by the column `share` in the workout table (which is an integer and contains a 1 if the workout is public).

I am trying call all groups that are associated with public workouts. I assume this needs to be done through a `named_scope` but I am unsure of the syntax.

In the groups_controller I am assuming I would call:

```
@groups = Group.public_groups.all
```

How should I write the `named_scope` in Group.rb? (I'm in rails 2.3.8)

```
named_scope :public_groups, ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :workout
  named_scope :public, {:conditions => 'workouts.share = 1', :include => :workout}
end

@groups = Group.public.all
```

Comment: awesome man. Worked great. Just not that familiar w/ named_scope yet.